android webRTC video not woroking
I've been developing a p2p call library using "io.github.webrtc-sdk:android", and it works great with audio calls, however, I cannot make the video calls work. Here's what I've done so far:

I've added the video constraint to my peerconnection config
I've created a videotrack from my local device and added it to the peerconnection
I know my local video track is correctly working since I can display it in my surfanceRenderer
I know a video stream is being created for my remote device since I get the callback for remote video track
I know a stream of data is coming from the remote device and it's of type VideoFrame.TextureBuffer 680*480px

But the surfaceRenderer shows nothing at all. Am I missing something here?

The issue was not with the peer connection but rather with how the code was set up. basically, the observers of the remote video track (flow), were not ready to receive this value. changing the observation order fixed this issue.
